# ObjectCache not caching json data

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, caching

I'm trying to cache some data returned as Json, problem is my cache does not seem to be caching the data and I do not know why, can anyone please have a look at my code and let a newbie know where he have gone wrong.

```
public class GetTravelAdvice : ITravelAdvice
{
    private static readonly string Key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FCO_URL"];

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>> GetFcoTravelAdvice(string country)
    {
        using (var ta = new HttpClient())
        {
            string cacheDataTravelAdvice = "FCOLocation" + RegexHelpers.RegexRemoveAllInvalidCharactersKeepWhiteSpace(country.ToLower());

            ObjectCache travelCache = MemoryCache.Default;
            var objectInCache       = travelCache.Get(cacheDataTravelAdvice) as IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>;

            if (objectInCache != null)
                return objectInCache.AsEnumerable();


            string ensureCountryStringIsValid = RegexHelpers.RegexRemoveAllInvalidCharactersKeepWhiteSpace(country);
            var url = await ta.GetStringAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Key, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ensureCountryStringIsValid), ".json")).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15) };

            travelCache.Add(cacheDataTravelAdvice, url, policy);

            return new[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(url) };
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line the `url` variable is a string instance, right?

```
var url = await ta.GetStringAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Key, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ensureCountryStringIsValid), ".json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is what you have stored in the cache: a `string` value:

```
travelCache.Add(cacheDataTravelAdvice, url, policy);
```

and here:

```
var objectInCache = travelCache.Get(cacheDataTravelAdvice) as IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>;
```

you are attempting to cast it to `IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>`. It's normal that if you have stored a string in your cache you cannot expect to get an `IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>` out from it.

So you need to read it as string:

```
string objectInCache = travelCache.Get(cacheDataTravelAdvice) as string;
```

and then deserialize it to the underlying object:

```
if (objectInCache != null)
{
    return new[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(objectInCache) };
}
```

The other possibility is to directly store your `IEnumerable<TravelAdvice>` instance into the cache:

```
var url = await ta.GetStringAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Key, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ensureCountryStringIsValid), ".json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
var data = new[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(url) };
travelCache.Add(cacheDataTravelAdvice, data, policy);
return data;
```

Comment: Hi Darin, looking at it now its so obvious, thanks for the help, I need to wait 3 minutes before I can mark your question as the answer.